# how to order parent by order field stored in the child relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have this relationship with 3 models

```
Content (1)
  ContentBlocks (many blocks belong to Content)
    ContentBlockSettings (many settings belong to ContentBlock)
```

I need to get ContentBlocks from DB and order them, I have a field called order and its stored in the ContentBlockSettings for each block.

How can I get back ContentBlocks from DB and also have them ordered by order field that is stored in the child relationship.

Please do not tell me to move the order field up to the ContentBlocks, I know that would be the easiest way out BUT there is very specific reason that I can not do this in my application.

So could you let me know if it is possible to order ContentBlocks by 'order' field which is stored in a child relationship. If possible, can you show me how to do it?

Update:

```
    foreach ($content->blocks as $key => $block) {
            $title = $block->settings;
            foreach ($block->settings as $key => $setting) {
                // dump('we here: ' . $setting['key']);
                if($setting['key'] == 'order') {
                    $block->order = (int)$setting['value'];
                    break;
                }
            }
    }


$content->blocks = $content->blocks->sortBy('order');

    return response()->json([
        'status' => 'success',
        'blocks' => $content->blocks
    ], 201);
```

If I comment out //$content->blocks = $content->blocks->sortBy('order');

what is returned to the client is:

[image]

if that line is enabled again what is returned is this:
[image]

Notice the difference? In first image blocks are array, there is [ at the begging if you look closely, and in second screen there is no [, there is length: 3 in first and no length in second screen

also:
[image]
As you can see above, order for imageblock is 3 and order for header block is 2

Even thought they are ordered on server, sortBy('order') did not change the array key so when I dd($content->blocks) on server, sure I get

```
0 => TitleBlock
2 => HeaderBlock
1 => ImageBlock
```

that is what gets printed when dd(), as you can see ImageBlock is still 1 and HeaderBlock is still 2 in the array.

How do I work around this so that client gets correct order?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `sortBy` collection method

```
$collection = collect([
    ["id"=>1,"product"=>['name' => 'Desk', 'price' => 200]],
    ["id"=>2, "product"=>['name' => 'Chair', 'price' => 100]],
    ["id"=>3, "product"=>['name' => 'Bookcase', 'price' => 150]],
    ]);

$sorted = $collection->sortBy("product.price")->toArray();

return: [
  ["id"=>2, "product"=>['name' => 'Chair', 'price' => 100]],
  ["id"=>3, "product"=>['name' => 'Bookcase', 'price' => 150]],
  ["id"=>1,"product"=>['name' => 'Desk', 'price' => 200]],
]
```

Comment: thanks, I updated my question. I already figured out I need to sortBy on collection, however still I end-up with problem on the client, see my updated question for details

Comment: to the browser only thing that mathers is that id is correctly ordered, if you send to client id in 3, 2, 1 it will render them in 1, 2, 3 anyways, since it ignores in what way you have sent it

Comment: is this work `$content->blocks->sortBy('settings.order')` ? 
if the data on server is ordered correctly, then I think the problem is on frontend (how you render it).

Comment: I do not need to do that, I do this: $block->order = (int)$setting['value']; problem is that server does not really reorder the array by changing the keys, frontend will allways render 1,2,3, does not matter if you send it as 1,3,2 its not frontend problem, this is how javascript renders json it recieves. What I really need is for server to update keys to 1 -> Title, 2-> Header, 3->Image and not do this:  1 -> Title, 3-> Header, 2->Image, see the difference?

Comment: what do you mean by `key`? where is it came from?